# Embedded `(quote ...)`

Tags: emacs, elisp

I installed some theme and it put the following in my `$HOME/.emacs`:

```
(custom-set-variables ; Your init file should only contain one of these
 '(custom-safe-themes (quote ("ea489f6710a3da0738e7dbdfc124df06a4e3ae82f191ce66c2af3e0a15e99b90"
                              "a8245b7cc985a0610d71f9852e9f2767ad1b852c2bdea6f4aadc12cce9c4d6d0"
                              "8aebf25556399b58091e533e455dd50a6a9cba958cc4ebb0aab175863c25b9a4"
                              default)))
 )
```

Why does it have a quote inside of a quote? Isn't that redundant?

Comment: Because it evaluates the value, and it wants it to be treated literally when that happens.

Comment: @Barmar I tried removing the `(quote ` and the corresponding paren and it still works. I don't know

Comment: emacs.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask this. It's not really about programming in general, but about how Emacs processes customization settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does it have a quote inside of a quote? Isn't that redundant?

It's not redundant, because it gives a different value; the general case in Lisp is `(quote foo) => foo` whereas `(quote (quote foo)) => (quote foo)`. So quoting and double-quoting are not interchangeable: one of them is correct while the other is not.

In this particular case there are multiple levels of evaluation so multiple layers of quoting are needed. The outer quote protects against the normal evaluation of arguments before function calls so that `custom-set-variables` receives the list `(custom-safe-themes (quote ("ea489..." ... default))))`.

This eventually gets passed to `custom-theme-set-variables` which calls `eval` on the 2nd element of the list `(quote ("ea489..." ... default))`.

> I tried removing the `(quote` and the corresponding paren and it still works.

It *seems* to work, but that's only because the custom setting functions catch the error. If you check `*Messages*` you will see `Error setting custom-safe-themes: (invalid-function ea489f6710a3da0738e7dbdfc124df06a4e3ae82f191ce66c2af3e0a15e99b90)`.

Comment: Does writing `'("ea489...` work the same as `(quote ("ea489...`?

Comment: Yup, `'foo` is identical to `(quote foo)`, always.